# Why touchesbegan: never gets called on a UIView after UIPinchGestureRecognizer is used?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath

I'm developing a drawing app which lets user to draw a UIbezierpath on a UIView (InsideView) subviewed by it's superView (self.view). I'm using conventional drawing codes in the InsideView like `touchesBegan:, touchesMoved:, touchesEnded:`and I'm handling pinch zoom code `handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer:` inside the viewController class (which is InsideView's superView).

When I draw first, I can do the pinch zoom after it but when I do the pinch zoom first, the drawing code (touchesBegan etc) doesn't get called after UIPinchGestureRecognizer is fired and it doesnt draw anything on InsideView. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

//Code in the InsideView (which is a UIView subclass and is a subview for self.view)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{              
                 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
                 if (self) {
                             path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
                             [path setLineWidth:7.0];
                             pointsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                             finish = NO;
                             }
                   return self;   
}   
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
                        [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
                        [path stroke];
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

                    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
                    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
                    [path moveToPoint:p];
                    [pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

                    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
                    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
                    [path addLineToPoint:p];
                    [self setNeedsDisplay];
                    [pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

                    [path closePath];

                    //Smoothing the path.
                    path.miterLimit=-10;
                    [self setNeedsDisplay];
                    finish = YES;
}

//Code in the viewController (InsideView's superView)
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        InsideView* sV = [InsideView new];
        [sV setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview:sV];

        //Pinch
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer*pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
        pinch.delegate =self;
        [sV addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
}
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

        if ([recognizer numberOfTouches] < 2)
            return;
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            lastScale = 1.0;
            lastPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        }
        // Scale
        CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - recognizer.scale);
        [sV.layer setAffineTransform:
         CGAffineTransformScale([sV.layer affineTransform],
                                scale,
                                scale)];
        lastScale = recognizer.scale;
        // Translate
        CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

        [sV.layer setAffineTransform:
         CGAffineTransformTranslate([sV.layer affineTransform],
                                    point.x - lastPoint.x,
                                    point.y - lastPoint.y)];
        lastPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
}
-(void)handlePinchWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer{
        sV.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sV.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
        pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: Try to call super in your touchesSomething methods. Also set finish to true when your gesture recognizer fires (just a guess...)

Comment: I suggest you to remove this code line `pinch.delegate = self;` as it is not necessary, maybe this solves your issue

Comment: Can you try removing the pinch gesture setup from drawRect and moving it to initWithFrame so that it happens only once?? also it is ridiculous to set up pinch everytime on drawRect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've developed a UIViewController where I used them together without any problem,s maybe a solution could be to move this logic from UIView to the UIViewController. So at `viewDidLoad` you can define the pinch recognizer like this

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
```

of course also the method `handlePinch:` should be moved to the `UIViewController`, together with `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, 
`touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:` methods

what you should change in these methods is that you should change

```
self
```

to

```
self.yourSpecificCurrentUIView
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I provided the pinch handling code inside the ViewController which is the superview of my drawing view and I provided the drawing code in the drawing view (which is a uiview subclass). It did solve the problem.